# Is it possible to simplify the SQL query used to produce the checksum based difference between a table and the given TVP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to write many entities into the database. I want to optimize it by:

1. Issuing a preflight request to compute the difference between the current data in the table and the new data in the process memory.
2. Only update/delete/insert the relevant records.

All the data is checksumed, so I am only going to compare the checksums.

Here is my preflight request:

```
;WITH src AS (
    SELECT cs.AdmClientSiteId, src.Id ClientId, Checksum, AuxId
    FROM @src src
    JOIN AdmClientSite cs ON cs.AdmClientMasterId = src.Id
    WHERE cs.AdmSiteId = @AdmSiteId
), dst AS (
    SELECT dst.AdmClientSiteId, cs.AdmClientMasterId ClientId, Checksum, LegalAuxId AuxId
    FROM AdmCustomerInfoLegal dst
    JOIN AdmClientSite cs ON cs.AdmClientSiteId = dst.AdmClientSiteId
    WHERE cs.AdmSiteId = @AdmSiteId
)
SELECT ISNULL(src.AdmClientSiteId, dst.AdmClientSiteId) AdmClientSiteId, ISNULL(src.ClientId, dst.ClientId) ClientId, ISNULL(src.AuxId, dst.AuxId) AuxId,
  CASE 
    WHEN src.Checksum IS NULL THEN 0        -- DBAction.DELETE
    WHEN dst.Checksum IS NOT NULL THEN 1    -- DBAction.UPDATE
    ELSE 2                                  -- DBAction.INSERT
  END Action
FROM src
FULL JOIN dst ON src.AdmClientSiteId = dst.AdmClientSiteId AND src.AuxId = dst.AuxId
WHERE src.Checksum IS NULL OR dst.Checksum IS NULL OR src.Checksum <> dst.Checksum
ORDER BY Action, ClientId
```

In this code:

- `@src` is a TVP
- `AdmCustomerInfoLegal` is the table to be updated
- The schema of `@src` is slightly different from that of `AdmCustomerInfoLegal`.

My question - can it be simplified/improved?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use [merge](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement which used in above condition.

I does not have time , please check this example and modify at your end.

```
create table temptable (id int, firstname varchar(50),  lastname varchar(50),  email       varchar(50),   homephone varchar(50))

insert into temptable values
(1,'aaa' , 'bbb', 'xxx@yyy.com', 1234444),
(2,'aaa' , 'bbb', null, null),
(3,'ccc' , 'ddd', 'abc@ddey.com', null),
(4,'ccc' , 'ddd', null, 34343322  )

select * from temptable

;with cte as
(
    select firstname, lastname
    ,(select top 1 id from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and ( b.email is not null or b.homephone is not null)) tid
    ,(select top 1 email from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and b.email is not null )  email
    ,(select top 1 homephone from temptable b where b.firstname = a.firstname and b.lastname = a.lastname and b.homephone is not null ) homephone
    from temptable a
    group by firstname , lastname
)

--select * from cte
merge temptable as a
using cte as b
on ( a.id = b.tid )
when matched 
    then 
    update set a.email = b.email , a.homephone = b.homephone    
when not matched by source then
    delete ;

select * from temptable

drop table temptable
```